# How to collect Chrome extension logs to a file

Tags: javascript, logging, google-chrome-extension, logstash, elastic-stack

How do I collect all the logs received from the users Chrome extension's console to a file, to use the ELK stack.
Do you know any tools can help me?

Comment: Note: this type of questions is _specifically off-topic_ on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: i have a similar question

Comment: by default its not enabled , check chrome site for steps https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6271282?hl=en